# Mongodb match array of objects

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

My schema:

```
const UserSchema = new Schema({
  firstname: { type: String },
  lastname: { type: String }
});
```

Let's say I have a collection `users` which contains the following documents:

```
{ "_id" : 1, "firstname" : "hello", "lastname" : "world" }
{ "_id" : 2, "firstname" : "hello", "lastname" : "earth" }
```

The client send to my server the search query below.
With mongoose, I need to query mongodb and it should returns me the user with the _id 1 which match the second object.

```
[{
  firstname: 'hello',
  lastname: 'you'
},
{
  firstname: 'hello',
  lastname: 'world'
}
{
  firstname: 'hello',
  lastname: 'hello'
}]
```

Please note the search query is not static, it can be:

```
[{
  firstname: 'fsefsefsef',
  lastname: 'fsefsecsfe'
},
{
  firstname: 'fsefsef',
  lastname: 'esfsf'
}
{
  firstname: 'zefzef',
  lastname: 'fzefzfz'
}]
```

In this case, the result should be an empty array because no user match any of the object in the query

Comment: I don't get it.

Comment: This is either a really tricky question or an obvious question: `UserSchema.findOne({ firstname: 'hello', lastname: 'word' }, function (err, user) {});`

Comment: @Mikey I need query the whole array, I just tried with a foreach and a promise all, it seems to work, but I feel like it's overkill

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass that object in the `find` method.

```
User.find(query[1])
```

Comment: The query is not something I can control, it's sent from the client, it's like a search query, which mean that I can't take manually only the 2nd object from that query and make a find ;)

Comment: It's really not clear then why do you need the array of queries, if you have the `user1` defined.